# "Error: Can't open display: wayland-0" on 22.04/gdm3

Tags: xorg, gdm, wayland

I am building a new workstation environment on Ubuntu Server 22.04 and manually installing just the minimal desktop components necessary to manage a half dozen libvirt/QEMU/KVM virtual machines (where I do all the real work).

I am having difficulty getting some of my tools (notably imagemagick) to run on the host desktop getting "Error: Can't open display: wayland-0".  I get the same running test programs like glxgears and xeyes.

If I disable wayland in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

```
[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
```

these apps all work (but create other problems for me that I won't go into here).

**UPDATE:** I decided to come at this from the reverse side: I built Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 instead and stripped out all the "productivity" software.  This works fine so there must be some package (some part of xWayland, maybe?) I was missing in the Server build but don't have time to identify it.

Comment: You may answer your own question helping others with this issue and gaining some rep in the process.

Comment: @ubfan1, doesn't feel like an answer to me.  I am still hoping someone can identify what I missed in the Server build so I can use it next time I build a workstation.